# use php and perl and R so on in a script like .sh of bash in linux? Is it possible?

Tags: php, linux, r, perl, bash

As the title says.
I want use php and perl in  script file like .sh of bash,but i don't if it is possible?
If that is possible,in bash script you can write php/perl/R,it will be very convenient!
Thanks.....
just like:

```
#/bin/bash
some bash code 
....
#/usr/bin/php
some php code 
...
#/usr/bin/perl
some perl code 
...
```

Comment: Sure you can. But you can try it yourself in 2 minutes, why ask it here?

Comment: sorry for that although i am a fresh man ....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#/bin/bash
#some bash code 
echo "hello from bash"

#some php code 
php -r'
  print "hello from php\n";
'

#some perl code 
perl -e'
  print "hello from perl\n";
'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is my first answer i get in stackoverflow!Excting!

Comment: Sometimes php or perl code is longer ,i try it,and your way also run well!But can I call php script file instead of the string of php code ?

Comment: It run well as you write.But call the php script file (.ph) ,is it possible?

Comment: @orange of course if it is an external script, ie. `php script.php; perl script.pl`

Answer (score 1):

Not really - at least not the way you expect it to.

To understand why, you need to understand how hashbang (`#!`) works.

Linux kernel, when it tries to execute file, checks first if it has first 2 bytes equal to `#` and `!`. If that is true, then remaining bytes until new line (`/usr/bin/perl` or `/usr/bin/php`) are considered name of the script executor. Now, process is restarted, and `/usr/bin/perl <original_script>` is tried to execute. Because `perl` is native Linux executable, resolving process finally can stop and program is executed normally.

Note that this process only looks for first 2 bytes of the file. You expect it to work for other lines, and this will not work.

However, what you can do is to write your program in one language - be it `bash`, `perl`, `php` or `R`. Then, every language has equivalent of `system()` call, which can be used to call functions written in "foreign" language. This is not recommended however, because it involves process forking - it can be slow and unreliable. It is much better to write everything in just one language. Of course, often you cannot avoid this and will have to call other scripts - just try to minimize it.

Comment: Typing so much words for me! Thanks!